# How do you make a facebook permission required when logging in?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Written a mobile app based on facebook api. App breaks if the user deselects birthday as a permission on the permissions screen. How can I make the permission required, so they cant deselect it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't directly possible, but it is *indirectly* possible. If you consider the below two Facebook features, you'll be able to get what you need.

**1. Re-requesting permissions**

In Graph 2.0, Facebook introduced the concept of a "declined" permission, where users can unselect the permission as you say. By default, if you run the login method in the SDKs, Facebook will not ask the user for the permission again.

However, there is a parameter called `auth_type` which you can input with "rerequest" to specifically re-ask for declined permissions.

See [Facebook's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) for more details.

**2. Checking permissions after login**

Using the [me/permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/permissions) API endpoint, you can see what permissions a user has provided:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "installed", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "public_profile", 
      "status": "granted"
    }, 
    {
      "permission": "user_friends", 
      "status": "declined" // the user didn't accept this one
    }
  ]
}
```

**Bringing it together**

Here's how your login flow can look:

1. Prompt the user to login
2. After the login is successful, check the user's permissions to see if they've granted all your "compulsory" permissions
3. If they haven't, show the user a message saying "you didn't provide the X permission, please login again to provide it"
4. Re-run the login method, but add the `auth_type` as "rerequest"
5. This time when the box opens up, the optional permissions will be compulsory. To proceed to the next step, they have to provide the permission.

Hope that helps!